# What is the reason my code cannot be parsed

Tags: node.js, json, dictionary, caldav

I am trying to parse data. But this error comes:

Error parsing response
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')

var result:

```
{
  multistatus: {
    '$': { xmlns: 'DAV:', 'xmlns:C': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav' },
    response: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

Code:

```
var data = result['D:multistatus']['D:response'];

          if(data) {
              data.map((event) => {
                var ics = event['D:propstat'][0]['D:prop'][0]['C:calendar-data'][0];
                var jcalData = ICAL.parse(ics);
                var vcalendar = new ical.Component(jcalData);
                var vevent = vcalendar.getFirstSubcomponent('vevent');
                reslist.push(vevent)
              });
            }
```

Error:

Error parsing response
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')

(Error to the line var data ...)

i expected to parse the data on correctly. Afterwards the events get filtered again.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but it's good practice and etiquette to actually ask a question.

Comment: Then your question is "What is the reason my code cannot be parsed?" is it not? If it is, then [edit] to say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data structure is this:

```
{
  multistatus: {
    '$': { xmlns: 'DAV:', 'xmlns:C': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav' },
    response: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

Which means you should use the actual property names `multistatus` and `response` and change this:

```
var data = result['D:multistatus']['D:response'];
```

to this:

```
var data = result['multistatus']['response'];
```

I don't know why you put the `D:` at the front of the property names.  Those are not present in the actual property names you show and must be removed.

Also, you should not be using `var` any more. Use either `let` or `const`.

---

The error message you get:

```
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')
```

Comes because this first part:

```
var data = result['D:multistatus']
```

results in `undefined` (since the `D:multistatus` property does not exist) and then you try to reference the second property off `undefined`, with this:

```
var data = result['D:multistatus']['D:response'];
```

you get that error as `undefined` is not an object and thus gives you an error when you try to reference a property on it.

Comment: thank you so much! It was actually a Npm package which had the "D:". Probably their ics caldav calender file was structered differently.